# Some character in the mailto's body is stopping the mail window to open....javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open a mail reply window using below in javascript:

```
window.location='mailto:'+to+'?subject='+subject+'&cc='+cc+'&body='+body;
```

The problem is there are some character(like quotes, special character etc) in body variable that gives an error message. The same code works if I give it a static simple body string.

The firefox error is something like

> Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Failure"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: (url) :: send_mail :: line 49"  data: no]"

body content:
"XXXXX"

Found out the reason guys...its not allowing me to send more than 1209 character. Posting this as a new question.

Comment: Consider posting the content in the body that you suspect is causing the issue. This will help give us some clues to work with. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you're passing a string into a parameter in a query string, and that string may contain characters that have other meaning in the url, you'll need to escape them using the following command:

```
escape(stringOfTextToEscape);
```

Thus, your window.location will look like this:

```
window.location='mailto:'+to+'?subject='+subject+'&cc='+cc+'&body='+escape(body)
```

This ensures that any special characters are converted to unicode escape sequences, which is safe to pass into a URL.

For more information, please see this [FAQ on escape, encodeURI, and encodeURIComponent](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm).

Comment: I tried that but its not working...the same body var is alerted correctly via a alert function like this:

alert(to+'_____'+from+'_____'+subject+'_____'+cc+'_____'+body);

Comment: You could try to narrow the problem down to the characters in question by cutting the body into 1/4ths, testing it one piece at a time, until you find the section that breaks it, then split it up into 4ths again and repeat until you get something small enough to post in your question. Good luck!

Comment: I have added the body content, have a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
window.location='mailto:'+to+'?subject='+subject+'&cc='+cc+'&body='+escape(body);
```

`escape()` function encodes special characters, with the exception of: * @ - _ + . /

So `escape("How are you? Come on!");` will give you result something like this: `How%20are%20you%3F%20Come%20On%21`

Comment: I tried that but its not working...the same body var is alerted correctly via a alert function like this:

alert(to+'_____'+from+'_____'+subject+'_____'+cc+'_____'+body);

Comment: not working out..looks like the space in the body is creating probs...still looking

Comment: Body content added, have a look